# PPT and Excel not generating in Office 2013

Tags: c#, .net, excel, automation, powerpoint

I am working on report automation project (Windows Application) and my dev environment have Visual Studio 2010 Professional version, Office 2013 installed.

I am using Microsoft Office Interop DLL files. I used below DLLs for Interop: `Microsoft.CSharp.dll`, `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`, `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.dll`. All these versions are 12.0.0.0.

This setting is working fine for Office 2010. But for Office 2013 it is messing.

Now let me describe how this reports gets generated. Firstly it creates an Excel file (which I consider as Intermediate file and it contains data and other charts is not generating the excel file), then from there we take those data to PPT file and make the expected output. I tried 14.0.0.0 versions for above mentioned dll also.

My application target framework is ".Net Framework 4 Client Profile", Platform Target "x86".

I can not use any paid library/DLL files.

Answer (score 0):

there is a easy way to work with Excel, by using EPplus open source library you can create and read excel file easy

use below command in your package manage console

```
Install-Package EPPlus
```

for creating PPT files also this link will be helfull : [How to use Automation to create and to show a PowerPoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/303718)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the flexibility of using 3rd party open source libraries.